# Replacing a dimmer with 2 blacks and a green with a smart switch

Tags: electrical

I have a smart wall switch that I want to install and it has 4 wires which are load, live, gnd-green, and Nuetral-white connections.

My dimmer has not markings on the connections but has 2 black wires connecting to 2 blacks in the box and a gnd (green).   This is not a 3 way but I found a red unused wire in the box,  Of course one of the blacks is the load the other is hot.  Could the red wire be the needed white wire and is miss colored?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What country are you in?  Are these wires in conduit?  Red, black, and white would make sense in a common non-metallic cable.  You sure one of the blacks isn't a white with tape on it?

Comment: Las Vegas, the wires from the Legrand dimmer are black and they connect to 2 black wires in the box.  There is no white wire, colored or otherwise.  Other than the green gnd wire, there is an unused red.  I am familiar with red used in 3 way but this is a single pole arrangement with the DR chandelier and there is no 2nd  switch to this room.

Comment: Sadly, the 10 year old dimmer doesn't have any terminating descriptions or even a gold contact as these 2 black wires just go into a sealed black enclosure on the back of the dimmer.

Comment: If you look at [this recent question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/158672/43874) the answer talks about wire colors.  Per code the red wire can't be used as a neutral.  The red was probably there so you could have the option of having two switches for a fan or have one hot always on and one switched, etc.  If the wires are in conduit, the red could easily be used to pull a new white wire.

Comment: Also, you're going to want to open up the electrical box of the light(s) that this switch controls to see what wires are there.

Comment: Gentlemen,  after tearing further in to my wall, I located the bundled white wires which were termintated.   I have now have it working per the smart switch instrutions althought I had to do a continuity check to the chandelier fixture to insure that the proper black wire was used as the load connection.  Many thanks for your expert opinion and this was definitely educational!

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer to your own question.  I would have never expected the wires would be bundled outside of the switch box - that's not a legal (per code) thing to do.  Glad it worked out!

Comment: @JPhi1618 I don't think they were, I think OP was looking at the leads coming out of the old dimmer (which were factory pigtails, not on screws) and hadn't yet looked in the back of the boxes to see the wirenut splices.